# Inserting user input from forms into hbs

Tags: node.js, express, redirect, templating, body-parser

I am trying to insert users' info into my template file after they have signup or signed in.

For instance, after user logs in, I want to fetch their name into a dashboard template.
Below is my code:

```
// Require modules
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const path = require('path');
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000
// Create the express server
const app = express();

// Use the bodyParser
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));

// Serve the static files
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'static')));

// Set the view engine
app.set('view engine', 'hbs');

// Making a get request to a template
app.get('/dashboard', (req, res) =>{
    res.render('dashboard', {
        username: req.body.username
    })
})

// make a post request
app.post('/users/signin', (req, res)=>{
    app.use('/users/signin', (req, res) =>{
        res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    app.get('/dashboard', (req, res) => {
        res.render('dashboard', JSON.stringify({
            user:{
                username: req.body.username
            }
        }))
    })
    })
})

// listen on a port
app.listen(port, ()=> console.log(`Server is up and running on port ${port}`));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try editing this line

```
res.render('dashboard', {user: req.body.username} );
```

On the template side, use `{{user}}`  where you want to place username.

For eg.

```
<h1>Welcome {{user}}</h1>
```